# Trying to understand callbacks using interfaces after the onPostExecute() method of an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask, callback

I have an AsyncTask anonymous class and I want to send the data that it generates back to an activity class without having to stall the UI thread by using .get(). I am having some trouble though. I have searched everywhere and I have found a lot of answers but nothing that really breaks it down step by step in a way that's really graspable (to me, anyway). So, here's my sequence:

a. Define an interface

> package com.example.jsonbourne;
>
> public interface AsyncTaskInterface {
>
> ```
>   public void callback(); }
> ```

b. In the AsyncTask class, create a listener method:

```
public void setListener(AsyncTaskInterface listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

c. in onPostExecute() set the callback on the listener, so that implementing classes will be called:

```
      @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    //CALLBACK INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION

                    mListener.callback();
            }
```

d. In the UI activity, set the listener on the AsyncTask object:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle firebug) {
        super.onCreate(firebug);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_user);
        ;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);

        gj = new GetJson(this);

        // CALLBACK INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION
        gj.setListener(this);
    }
```

(lv, gj are class objects declared right after the activity class declaration)

e. Finally, implement the interface callback method in the UI class:

```
public void callback() {
        ArrayList<String> al = gj.getData();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserList.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Synchronization complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

It doesn't work though. Any ideas? What I mean by "it doesn't work" is that the ListView does not get populated but it actually does if I call .execute().get() on the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, I solved the problem myself after thinking about it a bit more: in the code I posted the AsyncTask is never called so naturally the callback() method is never ran.

I simply added gj.getData() in my onCreate() method (so that the AsyncTask is ran) and it works perfectly.